# Which real numbers are contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\cos40+i\sin40)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, roots-of-unity, splitting-field

I have a field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\cos40+i\sin40)$. I would like to find all the real numbers in this field and prove that they form a subfield (S) and find $|S:\mathbb{Q}|$. And also calculate the splitting field of S.

I know that $\mathbb{Q}(\cos40) \leq \mathbb{Q}(\cos40+i\sin40) = \mathbb{Q}(\cos40, i\sin40)$.  And that $|\mathbb{Q}(\cos40):\mathbb{Q}|=3$. And $\mathbb{Q}(\cos40)$ only contains real numbers.

($\cos40+i\sin40$ is a primitive 9th root of unity)

My assumption is that S = $\mathbb{Q}(\cos40+\sin40)$. I have to show that $\cos40+\sin40$ could be written with the help of elements from $\mathbb{Q}(\cos40+i\sin40)$.
I believe I could calculate these in question if I knew $S$. I would be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: You should use radians, not degrees... And if you use degrees rather than radians, you should indicate so; the default argument unit for $\cos$ and $\sin$ in this context is radians.

Comment: Showing that the set of real numbers in this field extension forms a subfield is secretly trivial. Remember that the intersection of two subfields is always a subfield!

Comment: Hint: what is the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2 \pi i /9}) / \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk It is 6. In our case what are the 2 subfields?

Comment: An extension of degree 6 may in general have more than two nontrivial proper subextensions, but you're right that in this case there are only two. I don't think that matters here, though. Instead, use the tower rule to figure out the degree of $S / \mathbb{Q}(\cos 40^{\circ})$

Comment: @diracdeltafunk i think that it is 1.

Comment: Great! So you've found $S$ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In their series of comments, @diracdeltafunk seems to have led you almost all the way to the full answering of your questions. To cut to the chase, your number, call it $\zeta$, is a primitive ninth root of unity, and thus is a root of the *Cyclotomic Polynomial* $\Phi(X)=X^6+X^3+1$, known to be irreducible. If we set $\xi=\zeta+\zeta^{-1}=\zeta+\overline\zeta$, then it’s not at all hard to see that the minimal polynomial of $\xi$ is $X^3-3X+1$.

The Galois group of $\Bbb Q(\zeta)$ over $\Bbb Q$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z/9\Bbb Z)^\times$, a cyclic group generated by $5$. Since a cyclic group has just one subgroup of each possible order, there are only the two proper subfields of $\Bbb Q(\zeta)$, the quadratic field generated by the cube roots of unity (it’s imaginary) and the other, generated by $\xi=2\cos(40^\circ)$.